Codespaces Preview url doubled
I run a vue app in codespaces and when I start the preview server through vite the url in the browser bar is doubled:

https://blabla-pxjcg97-3000.app.github.dev/https://blabla-pxjcg97.github.dev/

Then of course no routing works.
How to debug this? Is this from vite.js from codespaces, or from vue?
Anyone see this before?
THis is the vite config:
I had to add the clientPort config because there is a firefox bug which makes the browser reloading constantly.
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

    // https://vitejs.dev/config/
    export default defineConfig({
      plugins: [vue()],
      resolve: {
        alias: {
          '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
        },
      },
      server: {
          hmr: {
            clientPort: process.env.CODESPACES ? 443 : undefined
        }
      },
    })


Could you please provide us with your vite.config.js file?

added the vite config
